# Thinking Sphinx multiple form fields

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Have been really struggling with this...

Form screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBWMW.jpg

Field name's/id's:
name | email | company_id | user_type

Controller:

```
@users = User.search(params[:name], params[:email], params[:company_id], params[:user_type])
```

Model:

```
define_index do
   indexes :name
   indexes :email
   indexes :company_id
   indexes :user_type
end
```

What is a proper way of doing this, have searched documentation but could not find any useful information :(

Answer (score 1):

The simplest searching method by fields through Sphinx is to pass a hash. You can eliminate nil-s to ensure that thinking_sphinx will be looking through the incoming request

```
conditions = {}
%w(name email company_id user_type).each do |i|
  i = i.to_sym
  next unless params[i]
  conditions[i] = params[i]
end

User.search(:conditions => conditions)
```

Comment: Thanks! But for some reason i am getting:
    index user_core: query error: no field 'company_id' found in schema

Comment: Have you run ts:rebuild (or re-indexed and restarted Sphinx) since adding the company_id field to your index definition?

Comment: Yes those fields existed before I started using Sphinx. I reindexed & restarted and now getting: `index user_core: syntax error, unexpected TOK_FIELDLIMIT near @email  @company_id  @user_type`

Comment: "company_id" should be **has**, not in **indexes**

Comment: Changed to "has" but still gettims same error
Here is what I have in my model:
`define_index do
    indexes :name
    indexes :email
    has :company_id
    has :user_type
  end`